# Implementing the 360 magic spin in smarty

Tags: smarty

I can't integrate the 360 magic spin in smarty templates. While adding the following code

```
<a class="Magic360" href="assets/spin-images/Bar-360-01.jpg" data-magic360-options="filename: Bar-360-{col}.jpg;">
```

While adding the attribute of data-magic360-options with filename, the screen will goes blank.

I amusing smarty 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

Smarty (PHP framework) counts all strings {..} like its own directives.

To avoid that, you should use the following code:

```
{literal}<a class="Magic360" href="assets/spin-images/Bar-360-01.jpg" data-magic360-options="filename: Bar-360-{col}.jpg;">{/literal}
```

or

```
<a class="Magic360" href="assets/spin-images/Bar-360-01.jpg" data-magic360-options="filename: Bar-360-{ldelim}col{rdelim}.jpg;">
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you forget `$` sign for `col` variable?

```
data-magic360-options="filename: Bar-360-{col}.jpg;"
```

Maybe you should use `{$col}`:

```
<a class="Magic360" href="assets/spin-images/Bar-360-01.jpg" data-magic360-options="filename: Bar-360-{$col}.jpg;">
```